# Can't pass a value from list item to function with onClick event when hyperlink element is nested in list item element

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to pass a parameter from a number of list items to differentiate them when clicked.

```
class SettingsGeneral extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      form_fields: ["Select option"],
      selectedSetting: "general",
      configSettings: {}
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const { param } = e.target.dataset;
    console.log(param); // e.currentTarget.value would be equivalent
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="settings-list">
        <li data-param="value" onClick={this.handleClick}>

         <a className="is-active" href="#g" ><i
         className="icon icon-settings-general"></i> General</a>


      </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

With the current code, when I do `console.log(param)` in the `handleClick(e)` method, I get "undefined"

When I remove the hyperlink element

```
<a className="is-active" href="#g" ><i
     className="icon icon-settings-general"></i> General</a>
```

so now it's just

```
   <ul className="settings-list">

    <li data-param="value" onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <h1> click</h1>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

And then I call the `handleClick(e)` and `console.log(param)` again, it logs "value" to the console which is exactly what I want.

Any idea why I can't pass a param to my `handleClick` function if there's a hyperlink element there? I don't want to remove the hyperlink at this time as it messes up the CSS and a UX designer created the CSS so I don't really have time to mess around with it.

Can I pass a value to my function with this hyperlink element there?

Comment: Which element do you get when you `console.log(e)`

Comment: what happens if you move the `onClick={this.handleClick}` directly to the `<a />` ... hyperlinks have their own click behavior and you may need to hijack it

Comment: @HolyMoly I tried that there, it still comes back undefined

Comment: gotcha, well there is always more than one way to skin a cat. while I can't explain the 'why' (hopefully someone else will be able to because it's always worth knowing) you can always pass the values directly on the onClick ie: `onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, someValue)}` then in the callback it get's passed in as a second param `handleClick(e, someValue)`

Comment: @HolyMoly Thanks, I wasn't aware it would work that way, I guess I'll settle that.

Comment: cool, glad to help. i am gonna include that as an answer else someone else will and get the points lol ;) if someone explains the why then you should give them the points tho, because that's more important to understand :)

Comment: honestly this seems like a React bug with the `onClick` handler. If you use `onMouseDown` instead, it would work (although you need to use `e.currentTarget.dataset`)

Comment: @oemera I did a `console.log(e)` It says `target: a.is-active.`

Comment: Then using `currentTarget` instead of `target`  should have done the trick, weird. You say `e.currentTarget.value` is equivalent, is this a typo? Did you mean: `const { param } = e.currentTarget.dataset;`? That should work.

Comment: So , turns out that if you used `e.currentTarget.dataset` it would work. I just stumbled on a codesandbox bug when trying to recreate the problem, see https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...while I can't explain the 'why' (hopefully someone else will be able to because it's always worth knowing) you can always pass the values directly on the onClick ie: 
`onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, someValue)}`

then in the callback it get's passed in as a second param `handleClick(e, someValue)`